# Xelatex and pdfLatex and thesis template

Tags: xetex, templates, greek

I'm trying to use [this](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis) template here to write my thesis. I am using xelatex because I need to write my thesis in Greek. The template works great when I compile it using xelatex without adding `xgreek` package. But after adding it all hell breaks loose :). This is what I get
I add this:

```
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

and get this:

```
10] [11]) (./Appendices/AppendixA.tex [12]
Παράρτημα \MakeUppercase {α\anw@true \anw@print \relax }.
! Undefined control sequence.
\MakeUppercase ...ppercaseUnsupportedInPdfStrings
l.3 \chapter{AppendixTitleHere}
% Main appendix title
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I don't know what can be wrong... I tried other templates and always get weird errors like environment not defined. But I see in the .sty file it is defined and so the .sty file is used inside the main.tex file... I am getting bit frustrated and really wanted to use latex...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  It is usually best to provide a complete compilable document demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I believe that template is for LaTeX, not XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming(while latex didn't welcome me nice so far :) )
@egreg Would love to add a minimum example but i don't think it would reproduce the problem because as i said this is a template that consists of many files. I don't have a problem with xelatex (which works fine in my document)but with xelatex and the specific template.

Comment: @NVaughan Yes it is a LaTeX template. But i couldn't find anywhere xelatex specific templates for thesis....:(...

Comment: I don't get any of the mentioned messages. In the meantime, at least `fontspec` was updated, the *current* template dates may 2014. I suggest to close as unclear.